# jQuery trigger loop animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

**EDIT: Link to code added**

I feel like it'd be good to give the context of the code since it seems to work without the ajax part.. here's the CodePen link to the project:
http://codepen.io/judysmilingeyes/pen/dNpxow

---

I am currently working on a project (a mini search engine) and got stuck on a jQuery question.

In theory it should work like this:
Upon click
 - if the search field is empty, displays error message
 - else append search result to the page, and display an animation which prompts the users to scroll down to check the results

I wrote the animation in CSS and it's working fine without JS/jQuery. To toggle on/off I first hide the HTML element and once the function enters the else statement I wrote a .show(), but in this case the loop of the animation is interrupted (it only runs once). Could anyone explain to me why this is happening/how to modify the code?

Here are the relevant HTML, CSS and JS/jQuery code. Much thanks in advance for any help/suggestions!

HTML

`<div class="animation"><p>Scroll down for results</p></div>`

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes results {
    from{
      top: 160px;
      opacity: 1;  
    }

    to{
      top: 180px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

.animation {
  -webkit-animation: results 1.5s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: results 1.5s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: results 1.5s linear infinite;
          animation: results 1.5s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 160px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.animation').hide();
  $('#submit').click(function(){
  var search = $('#search-field').val();

    //error message when the entry is empty
    if (search == ""){
      $('ul').empty();
      $('.main-body').append('<p class="error-message">Oops - did you forget to put in something?</p>');
    }

    else {
      //clear old results
      $('ul').empty();
      $('.error-message').empty();
      //get search results
      $.ajax({
        ...
      });

      $('.animation').show();
    } 
  });

});
```

Comment: try adding and removing `animation` class to the html element.

Comment: I ran your code locally and it works fine. I just had to take out the  $.ajax({
        ...
      }); part do the the js error. Here is the screen vid capture https://www.screencast.com/t/M0N2zFcNore.

Comment: This code works as expected for me: [See JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/noj9ncj9/)

Comment: @AdamWolski I tried that but it's still giving me only a flash of the animation. I've pasted the link to the project hoping it'd provide more context, could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Valius79 thank you - I actually had to use the ajax part to append the search results to the ul element that I had in HTML. Not sure if this was why the project was behaving weird? I've included a link to the project in the post, could you take a look and see if there's any way to work around it?

Comment: @bbailes thanks! I tried your JSFiddle page and it was working fine. However I realized that the ajax part is relevant too so I've included the original link to the project - hopefully this could provide more context and show that how it's behaving..

Comment: Why don't you use position absolute on animation element and place it inside the element that contains the input and the button and just postion is however you want?

Comment: In the codepen the `.show` wasn't inside the success callback function, though I haven't tested if that matters. But the animation div itself was below the results (the results were added to the `ul` element). Moving it up, it seems to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgowvq

Comment: @Valius79 I tried what you suggested - had to tweak CSS a little bit but it's working! Now I have one last question - could you explain why moving the animation into that div solves the problem? (Apologies for so many questions, as I've been learning to code for only a month or so) Thank you so much!

Comment: @Me.Name thank you! I figured that out with the help of Valius but I'm just not sure why this solved the problem - I'm guessing it has something to do with how HTML/CSS/JS code are executed in a browser, but could you explain a bit more, as I'm fairly new to coding?

Comment: Your animation worked the whole time. It was just running on the bottom of the page. So positioning it absolutely, you made sure it stays where you want it to show.

Comment: @Valius79 I see, thank you!